# Typo3 Migration 7.6 to 9

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

To migrate from Typo3 7.6. to 9, do I have to make an intermediate step via Typo3 8?

I have a Linux Server and the current PHP is 7.0. PHP would be updated as well.

Would like to get to the current version of Typo3 but not sure if a direct jump would cause more problems. (This is aided by an agency, but would like to get second opinion whether intermediate step makes sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always do an upgrade step by step.
It's also good to have this step for all the DB migrations and some manual stuff like raising PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the extensions and the level of your knowledge. I would also prefer the step from 7.6 to 9/10 via 8, but if the Extension is still from pi Age or early extras, i would prefer to rebuilt it from the scratch, also because of changing db routines and other depreciation stuff.